# Do we have to pay deductibles on medicare and medicaid separately?

Tags: united-states, health-insurance, medicare

My fiancé has been seeing a PTSD therapist for about five weeks, paying out of pocket for the sessions until her medicare deductible was met so she would be covered.

We just got a call from the therapist telling us that, miraculously, we now have to switch to medicaid for them to 'continue covering the sessions' now that our medicare deductible is met.

We really can't afford to keep paying out of pocket for these sessions, and had only budgeted for one deductible. Are we now going to have to pay out of pocket until a second deductible is met?

Comment: To be properly answerable we'll need to know what state you live in (and the state the provider is practicing in, if it's different). Medicaid is administered by each state individually, and there can be a lot of variation in how they handle coordination of benefits. Also sometimes relevant: is the Medicare through an Advantage plan, is your fiancé eligible for Medicaid (presuming they do not already have it), and would the Medicaid be/is it managed by a private insurer? And was "[them] continue covering the sessions" the actual phrasing the therapist used?

Comment: (I know that's a lot of clarification questions, but health insurance in the US is intricate and annoying to deal with. And while I can guess what the therapist meant, mistaken assumptions won't help anyone)